# Same Parse query finds the record in chrome js console but not in node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I have the following code trying to query and see if the record already exists and only save it if it doesn't exist:

```
var catalogErrQuery = new Parse.Query(CatalogError);
catalogErrQuery.equalTo("type", "duplicate_event");
catalogErrQuery.containsAll("data", [event.id, eventTimeMap[signature].id]);
catalogErrQuery.first().then(function(object){
    if (object === undefined) {
        var catalogError = new CatalogError();
        catalogError.set("type", "duplicate_event");
        catalogError.set("data", [event.id, eventTimeMap[signature].id]);
        catalogError.save();
    }
});
```

But some how when running the code in node. it never finds the record even though I can see the record in Parse data browser as well as when I try to run the same query in chrome js console. As a result, it saves a duplicate copy of the record even though it already exists.

"data" column is of array type and I'm storing an array of numbers. In the js console, the following query prints "found":

```
var catalogErrQuery = new Parse.Query(CatalogError);
catalogErrQuery.equalTo("type", "duplicate_event");
catalogErrQuery.containsAll("data", [9350524,101831404]);
catalogErrQuery.first().then(function(object){
    if (object !== undefined) {
        console.error("found")
    } else {
        console.error("not found")
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? So confused.

Answer (score 0):

The the two snippets differ on the `containsAll` line.  The ids mentioned in the second snippet are not parse object ids, which are 10 alphanumeric characters.  The second snippet as written won't find anything.

Replace those hard-coded ids with the expressions in the first snippet.  Or, if that's not feasible,

```
console.log("first id " + event.id + ", and second id " + eventTimeMap[signature].id);
```

and use that output in the second snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In my first example, both `event` object as well as `eventTimeMap[signature]` object are just javascript json objects. They are not Parse Object. So the IDs are indeed numerical, not strings. The values I put in my second example are indeed copy-n-pasted from log lines which I removed from the code I posted above.